# Call method of a const reference in a copy constructor

Tags: c++, reference, constants, copy-constructor

I'm using a copy constructor to take a `MapObject` and copy it and it's properties.
However, this object is already spawned into the game, so on construction I want to remove the object from the game.

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
MapObject::MapObject(const MapObject& _mapobject)
{
    _mapobject.Derez();
    Rez();
}
```

How can I accomplish that in the copy constructor without calling it on `const&`?

Edit:
Switching to a vector of smart pointers solved this issue altogether.

Comment: Are you sure that creating a **copy** should remove the original?

Comment: It sounds like you want to move it, not copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call it if `Derez` is `const`.

But to me, it seems like the design is wrong. Why creating a copy removes the original from the game? Why is the class responsible for removing instances of itself from the game in the first place? Why are you even trying to copy an object that's already in the game?

To me, this seems more important than actually calling that method.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a *mutable copy-constructor*:

```
MapObject::MapObject(MapObject& _mapobject) // << no const here
```

But then you are left with a *copy-constructor* that doesn't copy, and that is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise against having your copy constructor modify the logical state of its argument.  It's non-idiomatic, and is likely to lead to confusion down the line.

Instead, do something like this at the call-site:

```
MapObject o2 = o1;
o1.remove();
```